# Why in python 12.76/106 is 0.1200000000001 and not 0.12?

Tags: python-3.x

I used pythonista to divide 12.76 and the result is 0.12000000001 instead of 0.12, why?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at http://floating-point-gui.de . The answer you are getting is not wrong, everything depends on how much precision you want.

Comment: Maybe I solved with Decimal(‘12.72’)/106*100 that returns me Decimal(‘12.00’) that is what I expected. You have to import the decimal module (from decimal import *)

Answer (score 1):

Because computers do the calculation in binary.  But they also have limited bits to represent the numbers.  there was probably an overflow in the base-2 so the machine had to round up by 1 bit or something.  Then when it translated it to decimal, u get that .00000000000001

Comment: Is there a way to get the correct result in python?